# How to add new target to Internal Link in Sitecore Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, links

We are required to bring a custom target attribute in sitecore general link field called “Preview”

```
<a href=”xxx” target=”preview”>XXX</a>
```

We added a new item in Sitecore Core Database called “Preview” under `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets`
[image]

We are able to see the changes in Content Editor and the URL is reflected in the front end as expected.
[image]

But when we looked at Experience Editor, we did not see the new custom target populated on the target dropdown.

[image]

On investigation, we found that the dropdowns are coming from the `GeneralLink.xml` file present in `root/sitecore/shell/Override/Applications/Dialogs/GeneralLink`
So we added it manually in the file post then it reflected in Experience Editor Dropdown.

[image]
[image]

But when I select “Preview” and give OK it is not saving as preview and it saving as “Active Browser” instead.

How to ensure that we get the new target **Preview** when used from **Experience Editor, Rich Text Editor** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, actually, it is enough to inherit your implementation from

```
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.GeneralLink.GeneralLinkForm,Sitecore.Client
```

and override with your implementation

```
protected override void OnOK(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Then you can update `GeneralLink.xml` file with:

```
<CodeBeside Type="MyAssembly.MyImplementation,MyAssembly"/>
```

Or you can copy the updated `GeneralLink.xml` file under `\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Dialogs\GeneralLink` to follow best practices.

`OnOK` contains logic that processes link targets, so it is enough to fetch mentioned implementation using the decompiler tool and modify the code that will take into account your link target.